How to query ContentDocument of Email Template's Attachments?
I have an Email Template with 3 attachments. I want to query both of those attachments' Content Document. How can I achieve this case?

Salesforce documentation on Content object relationships is bad.  Here's an article with a good explanation https://appiphony.com/blog/contentdocument-contentversion-and-contentdocumentlink/.

Query from ContentDocumentLink by filtering on LinkedEntityId with the Email template Id (prefix 00X):
SELECT Id,ContentDocument.title,LinkedEntity.name FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = '00X000000000000000'

